# Display taxonomy term from id

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I want to display taxonomy term from it's id. I have the following code that get's me id of this term but I don't how to convert this id into term name to display it.

```
function menu_custom_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  dpm($items);
  $element = array();
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {     
    $element[$delta] =  l(check_plain($item['target_id']));    
    }  
  return array(
    0 => array(
      '#markup' => theme('item_list', array('items' => $item)),
    ),
  );
  return theme('item_list', array());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the taxonomy term name from ID.

```php
function menu_custom_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  dpm($items);
  $element = array();
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) { 
    $taxonomy = taxonomy_term_load($item['target_id']);
    $element[$delta] = $taxonomy->name;
  }  
  return array(
    0 => array(
      '#markup' => theme('item_list', array('items' => $item)),
    ),
  );
  return theme('item_list', array());
}
```

`$taxonomy->name`  will give you name of taxonomy term.

I hope this will help.
Thanks

Comment: it gaves me same id